# I'm trying to float a logo left and a group of links right in a div header

Tags: hyperlink, css-float

I'm trying to create an header where there's a logo to the left and a group of links lined horizontally side by side on the right.
this is my code below with an image of the result. I really need help please

[**thats the result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWVxx.png)

```css
#header{
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#1b2142;
    padding:0px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
     
}
.links{
    width:70%;
    float:right;   
    padding-top:10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.link ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    list-style: none;
    color:white;
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="logo"><img src="untitled.jpg" height="100px" width="100px" >
                <div class="links">
                    <ul>
                        <a class="link" href="#">Home</li></a>
               <li><a class="link" href="#">About Us</li></a>
               <li><a class="link" href="#">Contact Us</li></a>
               <li><a class="link" href="#">FAQ</li></a>
               <li><a class="link" href="#">View Users</li></a>
               <li><a class="link" href="#">Our Staffs</li></a>
               <li><a class="link" href="#">See testimonies</li></a>
               <li><a class="link" href="#">Address</li></a>
                        <li><a class="link" href="#">Alumis</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit this part of code as below. It should work.

```
.links{
    float:right;
    padding-top:10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.link ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    list-style: none;
    color:white;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The links class should have a correct text alignment in order to work this out.

Add that line to the `.links` styling:

```
text-align: right;
```

If you want them to be visualized horizontally, I would suggest you to use some flex display.

Comment: I just tried that it moved right while the links remain vertical but no longer in the center just moved to the right this time like in the image I posted

Comment: that's why I said you to try using the flex display with row direction. that should be the solution for your problem.